# $f(x) = 1 - \int_0^x [f(t)]^2 \ dt$ for all $x \ge 0.$. Calculus Homework Problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The Problem: Find the function $f(x)$ that satisfies
$f(x) = 1 - \int_0^x [f(t)]^2 \ dt$ for all $x \ge 0.$

What I've done: I tried solving the integral, and arrived at $\frac{F(x)^3}{3}.$ So from here, would I just be solving for the derivative of this "ultimate function" so to speak? Just lost on the integral part, I can take it from there once I know that part.

Comment: The integral is woefully wrong. Try differentiating and see what you get.

Comment: differentiate to get an easy equation.

Comment: What is $F(x)$?  In any case I would start with $f'(x)=-f^2(x)$.

Comment: Thank you all for the helpful comments, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the integral equation
$$y(x)=1-\int_0^x y(t)^2\mathrm{d}t$$
Since integral equations that aren't in Volterra or Fredholm form are a real pain, let's convert this into a differential equation. Using the FTC, we find that
$$y'(x)=-y(x)^2$$
This equation is *separable*. What I mean is we can write this as
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=-y^2$$
So
$$-\frac{\mathrm dy}{y^2}=\mathrm dx$$
Integrate both sides!
$$-\int\frac{\mathrm dy}{y^2}=\int\mathrm dx$$
$$\frac{1}{y}=x+c_1\implies y(x)=\frac{1}{c_1+x}$$
More precisely if we happen to have an initial condition, say $y(0)=y_0$ then we can write
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1/y_0+x}$$
**EDIT:**

Going back to the integral equation we find that
$$y(0)=1-\int_0^0y(t)^2\mathrm dt=1$$
So our solution incorporating the IC is
$$y(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$$
A quick check:
$$1-\int_0^x\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}\mathrm dt=1-\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{x+1}{x+1}-\frac{x}{x+1}=\frac{1}{1+x}$$
As needed.

Comment: Wow, much appreciation for this answer. I had already arrived at the solution a while back, but for those in the future who wish to know the answer, I appreciate you coming here to write out.